# Ubuntu Touch - Today scope weather section

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

In the Today Scope, how do I add anothet location to the weather section to allow two sets of weather reports to be seen. I want to see my current location and London.

Comment: I don't think you can right now. It may be possible in future once this feature http://pad.lv/1458235 arrives.

Comment: Hopefully, as it would be good if we can in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is a an app called 'Forecast' where you can set up multiple locations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed it, but it is not what I am looking for. Hopefully the new improved scope may allow me to do it.